# Transparency css for placeholder not working for mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I want to make input fields with zero transparency for `placeholder` text

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here"  />
```

I used following css properties which fixed transparent in Firefox but it still shows  text with transparency on iPhone and android browsers

i am using following css

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
opacity:  0.8;
-webkit-opacity:0.8;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  opacity:  0.8;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  opacity:  0.8;
}
```

How can i make `placeholder` with 100% opacity for android & iphone browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can control your view in the mobiles or  in any device through the "media query"

media Query : is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

for example for the iphone6 you can use this code to hide the transparency or to set any css rule  you want for this screen size,

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* your style here */}
```

> Update

You can use Important to set the rule and give it the priority, check the code below :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
     opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you got my question right, My page is responsive i only want to show placeholder text in all browser with 100% opacity.

Comment: I am so sorry if I didn't got you question , So you need to set  the opacity to 100% in the android and IPhone browser because it didn't work when you put it as a general rule , right ?!

Comment: Yes, You are right i want to show placeholder text with `opacity:1` but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I resolve transrency issue by using RGBA

Opacity was not working as it works for the whole element so i used RGBA

`color:rgba(0,0,0,1);`

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
opacity:  0.8;
-webkit-opacity:0.8;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  opacity:  0.8;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  opacity:  0.8;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

}
```

sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vbMw3/699/